# Firebase custom subdomain www redirect to non-www

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I added CNAME for `my.example.com` and it works well, problem is with `www.my.example.com`.

I tried to create another CNAME record for `www.my.example.com` pointing to firebase, but there is SSL Certification Warning.

How can I redirect `www subdomain` to `non www`? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

According to [Firebase hosting docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) what you're trying to do won't work.

> Subdomain depth: Subdomains of up to one level of depth are supported.
>   Deeper subdomains, like my.app.example.com, are not allowed.

You could potentially do the redirect through another provider. Some DNS providers for example will do redirects for subdomains.